# Retrieving data from promise | Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, angular-promise

I'm trying to add a top posted section on my dashboard. Getting the top 'captures' aka posts wasn't an issue, though working with Auth0, I need to link the user info with the corresponding users.

Currently I am getting a promise in my dataObj that I pass along to check who made the most votes, but seeing it's asynch I'm having issues retrieving the data and putting it into the users variable:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'captureApi', 'userApi', 'filterFilter', '$q', function($scope, $http, captureApi, userApi, filterFilter, $q){
    $scope.captures = [];
    $scope.pageSize = 4;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    $scope.topPosters = [];



    captureApi.getAllCaptures().then(function(res) {
        $scope.captures = res.data;

        userApi.getUsers().then(function(res){

        $scope.getCount = function getCount(strCat){
                return filterFilter( $scope.captures, {userId:strCat}).length;
            };    

            var users = res.data.users;
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
                var userId = users[i].user_id;
                console.log(userId);
                console.log($scope.getCount(userId));

                $scope.user = userApi.getUser(userId).then(function(res){
                   $scope.userInfo = res.data;
                   console.log($scope.userInfo);
                   return res.data;
                });

                var dataObj = {
                    user : $scope.user,
                    userId : userId,
                    amountPosted : $scope.getCount(userId)
                    };

                    $scope.topPosters.push(dataObj);
            }
            console.log($scope.topPosters[0].user);
        });
    });
}]);
```

As you can see, I get all the captures, then I count them depending on their userId.
Once this is done I add them to the dataObj.
But in between I'm trying to add the user information (using `userApi.getUser(ID)` and also add their information to this dataObj. At the moment I'm getting a promise. How do I convert this into the dataObj of each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load all data before pushing to topPosters. An example:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'captureApi', 'userApi', 'filterFilter', '$q', function ($scope, $http, captureApi, userApi, filterFilter, $q) {
$scope.captures = [];
$scope.pageSize = 4;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.topPosters = [];

$scope.getCount = function getCount(strCat) {
    return filterFilter($scope.captures, {userId: strCat}).length;
};

$q.all({captures: getAllCaptures(), users: getUsers()}).then(function(collections) {
    $scope.captures = collections.captures;
    return collections.users;
}).then(function (users) {
    return $q.all(users.map(function (user) {
        return getUserById(user.userId);
    }));
}).then(function (users) {
    $scope.topPosters = users.map(function(user) {
        //I think your user has propery "id" or similar
        return {
            user: user,
            userId: user.id,
            amountPosted: $scope.getCount(user.id)
        }
    });

    console.log($scope.topPosters);
});

function getAllCaptures() {
    return captureApi.getAllCaptures().then(function (res) {
        return res.data;
    });
}

function getUsers() {
    return userApi.getUsers().then(function (res) {
        return res.data.users;
    });
}

function getUserById(userId) {
    return userApi.getUser(userId).then(function (res) {
        return res.data;
    });
}

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks.. worked like a charm, I should apply it using this methode more.

Comment: I was wondering if I could chat with you in a realtime for a bit to ask a couple questions?

Comment: Skype: flamps1. But I haven't much free time, I am working